# Have I missed something when it comes to using os commands?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to use ths os.system('cls') command to clear my python shell. I am expecting my hello world line and the file directory to be cleared when the code is run however, the code remains uncleared with no error appearing in the shell. I'm really not sure how to proceed.

I am running the code on windows in the python IDLE, and testing in the idle shell. I would like the shell to be completely cleared so that it just looks a bit more tidy for the user.

The code in question:

```
#print hello world
print("hello word")


#clear screen
import os
os.system('cls')
```

Comment: it should successfully clear the `hello world` message.  Are you running this in an IDE?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly do you mean by "clear my python shell"? What shell are you referring to? Exactly what steps do you take in order to run the program? It's important to understand that `os.system` is used to **run a different, already existing program** that is on your computer - Python doesn't have "commands", and `cls` especially isn't one of them. The `cls` program can **only** clear a **terminal window**, the sort of thing that you get by choosing `Run...` from the Start menu and inputting `cmd`.

Comment: 'cls' is for windows and 'clear' is for linux. If you are using something like Spyder then it will not work. It should work if you are executing your .py in your terminal.

Comment: Apologies for my lack of clarity. I am running the code on windows in the python IDLE, and testing in the idle shell. I would like the shell to be completely cleared so that it just looks a bit more tidy for the user.

Comment: @Alexander I am using IDLE. I’ll try running the code an a PC in college cause I’m highly concerned it’s my pc causing the issue.

Comment: @user20189268  `cls` is a terminal command.  If you enter `cls ` into the idle shell does it clear the screen?

Comment: @Alexander It worked in the terminal, but I need it to work in idle, or I need something that can clear the screen in idle

Comment: It can't work in idle.... Idle is just a python shell.  It doesn't run terminal commands.  Idle is a pretty terrible tool anyway.  You would be better off using an ipython shell